# Create proxy with dynamic functions

Tags: javascript

I want to change styles and get them, using this method:

```
style(element).color("red") // Change color to red
style(element).color // get current color
```

This is what I tried:

```
let styleProxy = {
  get: (object, property) => {
    return (value) => {
      object[property] = value;
      return new Proxy(object, styleProxy);
    }
    return object[property];
  }
}

let style = (element) => {
  return new Proxy(element.style, styleProxy);
}


let element = document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0];
let test = style(element)
  .color;
```

I know, that these functions are created dynamically but how do I check if I'm calling this proxy function-based or property-based.

Comment: You don’t. Consider how jQuery, with a similar API philosophy, would require `.color()`. Proxies allow for all sorts of ill-advised magic, but the fundamentals of how method calls in JavaScript work (they’re just properties) are unchanged – and that’s a good thing.

Comment: This is not how javascript works. Consider `myColorSetterFunc = myStyle.color` - would that be a "property" or a "function" call? Theoretically, you can supply your functions with `Symbol.toPrimitive` that returns a value, but that would be a really nasty and fragile thing.

Comment: This is not possible. A value cannot be a string and a function at the same time.